# WordPress Theme different width

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to achieve to following design:

[image]

This is what I got so far:

[image]

I'd like to have the bottom images as in my design example.

This is, how my single.php looks like. I just can't find a solution that is responsive and works with my design :(

```php
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="container px-4">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-20">

        <article class="flex-auto w-[800px]">

        <?php if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

        </article>

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>
</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Your bottom images should be placed at the height of the header and footer

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that your bottom image is within the post content itself, and that is sitting next to a sidebar on the right. That image, or images, won't span the full width of the page if the sidebar is taking up some of that area. So, those two bottom images would have to be loaded after the post content and after the sidebar to achieve the design you're looking at.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. That is correct, the images are part of the content. Is there a possibility to exclude the images from the content area and display them separately? Or do you know a plugin to upload images separately rather than posting them as a block in gutenberg?

Comment: You could look into building your own page templates with the use of Advanced Custom Fields. I'm not sure if that would be outside your wheelhouse, but that's generally how to solve this kind of thing. It requires PHP and https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: Advance Custom Fields looks like a nice solution for the issue. I can upload my images via a custom field and call that field in my single.php.